# List all the filenames under a folder containg zipfiles in Linux/Unix

Tags: linux, unix, directory, directory-structure

How to list all the files inside a folder containing multiple zipfiles.
I know I can use `unzip -l filepath.zip` or `zipinfo -1 filepath.zip`. But is there any way where I can list all the files at once?

For e.g.: The folder structure is as below:

```
2019 Folder/
    201901.zip/
        data/
            rawfiles/
                file1
                file2
                ...
    201902.zip/
        data/
            rawfiles/
                file1
                file2
                ...
    201903.zip/
        data/
            rawfiles/
                file1
                file2
                ...
```

I want to list all the files inside the raw files folder from all the zip folders (201901.zip,201902.zip etc)

Comment: Something like `find 2019 -name "*.zip" -exec zipinfo -1 {} \;` ? probably pipe to `| grep rawfiles`

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 zip files with 3 txt files in each rawfiles directory and 2 data.txt files in each data directory. This is my output:

```
$ for zipfile in *.zip; do zipinfo -1 $zipfile | grep "data/rawfiles/."; done
data/rawfiles/raw1.txt
data/rawfiles/raw2.txt
data/rawfiles/raw3.txt
data/rawfiles/raw4.txt
data/rawfiles/raw5.txt
data/rawfiles/raw6.txt
data/rawfiles/raw7.txt
data/rawfiles/raw8.txt
data/rawfiles/raw9.txt
```

Explanation: for each zip-file in the current directory, perform `zipinfo` with the argument `-1` which only outputs the filenames without additional information, then pipe this into `grep` and filter out the sole directory name by grepping `rawfiles/.` instead of just `rawfiles`, because the `.` will match any character following the literal `rawfiles/`.

If you want to filter away the `rawfiles/` prefix, you can also pipe it into `sed`:

```
$ for zipfile in *.zip; do zipinfo -1 $zipfile | grep "data/rawfiles/." | sed s~data/~~g | sed s~data/rawfiles/~~g; done
raw1.txt
raw2.txt
raw3.txt
raw4.txt
raw5.txt
raw6.txt
raw7.txt
raw8.txt
raw9.txt
```

If you want to list the files inside any directory instead of the current directory, just provide a different path to the for loop:

```
$ for zipfile in /absolute/or/relative/path/to/final/directory/*.zip; do
```

If you want to output it in a single line instead of a newline per file, simply wrap it into another `echo` command:

```
$ echo $(for zipfile in *.zip; do zipinfo -1 $zipfile | grep "data/rawfiles/." | sed s~data/~~g | sed s~data/rawfiles/~~g; done)
raw1.txt raw2.txt raw3.txt raw4.txt raw5.txt raw6.txt raw7.txt raw8.txt raw9.txt
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. To add to this, I want to list all the zip file names inside the rawFiles folder.  So the heireachy is like 2019 -> 201901.zip -> data-> rawFiles-> file1.zip, file2.zip, file3.zip. And, I want to list these file1, file2... Sorry I am very new to this and still learning.

Comment: what exactly did not work with my solution? Ah do I understand correctly that the hierarchy is `data->rawFiles` and not like it seems from your original post that there are two directories inside your zip files where only one of them is interesting, like `file.zip->data` and `file.zip->rawFiles`?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, try: `for zipfile in *.zip; do zipinfo -1 $zipfile | grep "data/rawfiles/." | sed s~data/~~g | sed s~data/rawfiles/~~g; done` ... you can always adapt the paths in this expression to your needs. just depends on your local file structure.

Comment: also you could add `-i` to your `grep` in case you missed some case sensitivity and it did not work:  if you `grep rawfiles` but the directory is called `rawFiles` (see the uppercase F) it will not work. if you `grep -i rawfiles` it will still work with uppercase letters...